# How to search a string case insensitive and (R) using regular expression in a text file using Python

Tags: python

I have string called "Micro(R) Windows explorer" in a text file How to search Case insensitive and (R) also match using Regular expression
code is

```
with open(logfile) as inf:
            for line in inf:
                if re.search(string,line,re.IGNORECASE):
                    print 'found line',line
```

but this string "Micro(R) Windows explorer" is not accepting giving error.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ what have you tried? there are many examples of just such a request on this site. just look a little harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a case-insensitive search, start your regex with `(?i)` or compile it with the `re.I` option.

To match `(R)`, use the regex `\(R\)`. Otherwise, the parentheses will be interpreted as regex metacharacters (meaning a capturing group), and only the string `"MicroR Windows Explorer"` would be matched by it.

Together:

```
with open(logfile) as inf:
    regex = re.compile(r"Micro\(R\) Windows Explorer", re.I)
    for line in inf:
        if regex.search(line):
             print 'found line',line
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a regex:

```
with open('C:/path/to/file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'micro(r) windows explorer' in line.lower():
            print(line)
```

Comment: Good idea. Hard to tell whether lowercasing all the lines would be faster or slower than a regex, but in this case, a regex is not actually needed.